# How To Pivot Table Visualizer in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, pivot-table

I have some measures and a calculated field from a dataset that show me the following:

[image: Standard table with Months as the Rows and Percentiles as Columns]

*The highlighted row/column is just to show the different output.*

This works great except that the data needs pivoting to looks like this:

[image: Ideal table with Percentiles as Rows and Months as Columns]

I have tried to do this with a Matrix Visual but it seems you can not put Measures in for the Rows.  I have looked into it on the web and nothing is really doing what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your months as columns and then go to the `Format` pane, `Values` section, and toggle the option `Show on rows`:

[image: Show on rows]

Comment: That did it.  In the `Fields | Rows` I have nothing, `Column`s just has `Months` and the `Values` are my 5 (Min, 25%..., Max) plus your `Formatting | Values | Show on Rows`.  Thank you so much.